# Python Generating a Shadowmap from a Heightmap

Tags: python, shadow-mapping, heightmap

I've recently been experimenting with Python and PIL to generate heightmap images using simplex noise.  The generated heightmaps are simply 2D numPy arrays with height values ranging from 0-1. I expanded upon this by implementing biomes based on the height values and thresholds, and converting them to RGB values.  I want to experiment further by implementing rudimentary lighting, although I'm unsure how to implement the steps I believe need to be performed:

- Create a shadowmap of size, initialised to 1, assuming all elements are lit
- Create a sun at an arbitrary position, such as (0, 0, 2).  This would be the upper left corner at double the height of the maximum value within the heightmap
- Loop through the heightmap, and for each position (P):

  - Draw a line (L) from the sun to P and obtain all elements within the heightmap that intersect L
  - Loop through each intersecting element and determine if the height of the element is greater than the height of L at the current position.  If it is, then the sun is blocked, iteration can be stopped, and P within the shadowmap can be set to 0

I understand how to implement the shadows once I have a shadowmap based on the heightmap, but i'm struggling with how I would get a list of elements between the sun position and a target position within the heightmap.  Alongside that, how would I determine the height of the line between the sun and target position, at an intersecting position?

I appreciate any help!  Below is the script to generate heightmaps:

```
from PIL import Image
import random
import opensimplex as simplex
import numpy as np

#noise
#Produce a noise value depending on an amount of octaves and its corresponding amplitude via @amps, and an exponent @exp
def noise(nx, ny, amps, exp):
    #Rescale simplex noise output from -1.0:1.0 to 0.0:1.0
    def sn(nx, ny):
        return simplex.noise2(nx, ny) / 2.0 + 0.5
    
    e = ampTotal = 0

    #Iterate amplitude values for each octave
    for amp in amps:
        ampDiv = 1 / amp
        ampTotal += ampDiv

        #Sample different areas of noise to avoid correlation
        e += ampDiv * sn(nx * amp, ny * amp)

    return (e / ampTotal) ** exp

#normalise_heightmap
#Rescales noise values depending on @min and @max to the 0 to 1 range
def normalise_heightmap(min, max, size, heightmap):
    scale = max - min

    for y in range(0, size[1]):
        for x in range(0, size[0]):
            heightmap[y, x] = (heightmap[y, x] - min) / scale

    return heightmap

#generate_heightmap
#Creates a numPy array of noise values
def generate_heightmap(seed, size, freq = 4, amps = [1.0, 2.0, 4.0, 8.0], exp = 2):
    simplex.seed(seed)
    heightmap = np.zeros(size)

    min = 1
    max = 0
    freqX = size[0] / freq
    freqY = size[1] / freq

    for y in range(0, size[1]):
        for x in range(0, size[0]):
            nx = x / freqX
            ny = y / freqY
            nv = noise(nx, ny, amps, exp)
            heightmap[y, x] = nv

            if nv < min: min = nv
            if nv > max: max = nv
   
    return normalise_heightmap(min, max, size, heightmap)

#generate_image
#Creates an image from a heightmap
def generate_image(heightmap):
    img = Image.fromarray(heightmap.astype("uint8"), "L")
    img.show()

heightmap = generate_heightmap(int(random.random() * 1000), [256, 256])
generate_image(np.multiply(heightmap, 255))
```

Comment: You may want to use [A Fast Voxel Traversal Algorithm for Ray Tracing](http://www.cse.yorku.ca/~amana/research/grid.pdf) to scan across the cells of your heightmap, comparing the range of heights in that cell to the range of heights of your ray in the interval crossing that cell. If you detect an overlap, you can do a conventional ray vs triangle check with two triangles spanning the four corners of the cell.

Comment: The answer to your question as asked is trigonometry... Ignore height and you've got  a 2D grid and a line. You know the grid cell centres and dimensions (and thus bounds). The formula for dist. from a point to a line is easy to find online. Likewise, the height is just Pythagoras, with the "adjacent" (base) being the distance between the cells being tested. The angle you know (the sun is fixed) so you can use `Tan(angle)=Opposite/Adjacent`. That said, this is all _extremely_ slow... Multiple loops per cell. I can't help but feel you'd be better with a different approach like DMGregory's